# Labeling a picture, refering back to it in the document

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a code for a picture, but I want to label it and referred back to it in the document. Below is the code for my simple picture

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-0.354692864000007,-0.11281228800001052) rectangle (6.255530239999983,3.4942891519999906);
\fill[color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.1] (0.,0.) -- (1.,3.) -- (6.,3.) -- (5.,1.) -- cycle;
\draw [color=zzttqq] (0.,0.)-- (1.,3.);
\draw [color=zzttqq] (1.,3.)-- (6.,3.);
\draw [color=zzttqq] (6.,3.)-- (5.,1.);
\draw [color=zzttqq] (5.,1.)-- (0.,0.);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=qqqqff] (0.,0.) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=qqqqff] (-0.2540295680000072,0.07173708799998953) node {$B$};
\draw [fill=qqqqff] (1.,3.) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=qqqqff] (1.1217021439999906,3.2426309119999903) node {$A$};
\draw [fill=qqqqff] (6.,3.) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=qqqqff] (6.104535295999983,3.2426309119999903) node {$D$};
\draw [fill=qqqqff] (5.,1.) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=qqqqff] (5.165011199999984,0.9609295359999899) node {$C$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

(code I got from GeoGebra, In case you are wonder, I have the colors and packages and others defined in my preamble.

Comment: For labeling you need a caption of picture (labels should follow after caption in form something as ``\label{my figure}``. Later in text you references it with ``\ref{my figure}``. How you put your picture in your text?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to include this in a float and reference it that way.  I'd suggest a figure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
Happy tikZ picture stuff
\caption{tikZ picture!}
\label{fig:tikzpic}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]

Reference Figure \ref{fig:tikzpic} at \pageref{fig:tikzpic}!

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

That will give you this:

[image: Reference page]

You can see the figure on the top, with the reference just before the last paragraph, including reference by both number and by page.

Note that the figure will "float" to a place where LaTeX considers a good position; you can (somewhat) control this by using the optional argument with "h" (here), "t" (top of a page), "b" (bottom of a page), or "p" (on a special float page); you can reference more than one to give LaTeX a choice.  E.g., `\begin{figure}[htbp]`.  There are also packages which will give you finer control over this; searching TeX.SE should help.

Hope that helps.